# How do I count within conditional foreach binding knockout 3.4.0

Tags: knockout.js

I'm binding to an observable array using foreach, I also use If within foreach to test a condition before binding. I want a count of bound elements.
$index will not work since it will leave gaps from elements that do not satisfy condition.

I thought of using a function but how do I initialise count to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a computed that would run through your array, apply some conditions and output the filtered array - then you could normally use $index()

e.g.

```
this.filteredArray = ko.computed({
    owner: this,
    read: () => {
        let filteredBySomething = ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.testArray(), (item: any) => {
            return item.id === /* some logic here */;
        });
        let result = filteredBySomething ? filteredBySomething : this.testArray();

        return result;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this opened my mind, I managed to implement such with few modification to ES5 script. I wasn't aware of arrow functions in js; even enabling ES6 did not help run this beautiful code. I'm using VS2013 editor. It keeps reporting syntax erro on => operator.

Comment: You can rewrite `() => {}` as `function() {}` BTW. I'm using Typescript in VS2015

Comment: Thanks again, that's what I did, I will then dig into typescript I like this kind of code.